# How to read a text file and output the words in the reversed order? Python

Tags: python

So I'm working on a code that reads a text and outputs on the screen the words in a reversed order meaning if the original text was

```
hello world
how are you
```

to:

```
you are how
world hello
```

I get it to partially work, the problem is that it outputs it in a single column, but I want it to be in lines.

the code is

```
for a in reversed(list(open("text.txt"))):
    for i in a:
        a = i.split()
        b =  a[::-1]
        final_string = ''
        for i in b:
            final_string += i + ' '
        print(final_string)
```

Comment: It makes code easier to understand when using meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 7):

You have one loop too many:

```
for a in reversed(list(open("text.txt"))):
    for i in a:
```

The first loop produces the lines in the file in reverse order, so `a` is bound to each line. The second `for` then loops over *each individual character* in that line. You then proceed to 'reverse' that character (or an empty list when that character is a space or newline).

You are already using `reversed` for the file, you can use it for the lines too; combine it with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
for line in reversed(list(open("text.txt"))):
    words = line.split()
    reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    print(reversed_words)
```

Or more concisely still:

```
print(*(' '.join(l.split()[::-1]) for l in reversed(list(open('text.txt')))), sep='\n')
```

Demo:

```
>>> with open('text.txt', 'w') as fo:
...     fo.write('''\
... hello world
... how are you
... ''')
... 
24
>>> for line in reversed(list(open("text.txt"))):
...     words = line.split()
...     reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
...     print(reversed_words)
... 
you are how
world hello
>>> print(*(' '.join(l.split()[::-1]) for l in reversed(list(open('text.txt')))), sep='\n')
you are how
world hello
```

Comment: ah thanks, the first one was the right one, now I just have one question, what does exactli reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(words)) do, if you could explain it to a noob. I would really apreciate that

Comment: @AleksČerneka: `reversed(words)` gives you the words in reverse. `' '.join()` takes the words and concatenates them together, putting the `' '` in between each word.

Comment: Ooops. I see that now. Sorry about that.